# com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1 XCode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode

I'm getting this error.

"The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)"

I can't even see the main.storyboard in XCode, this error pops up if you try to view it.

I just updated to version 8.2.1, and this started happening.

I just downloaded a new version from my git that my partner uploaded (works fine on his end.

Any ideas what's causing this? Is there a bug in the new XCode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following up - seems to be a merge conflict on the main.storyboard file. Best solution I could find was to download my partner's main.storyboard and upload it into the project. This solved the issue!